# Update guarantees in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

Is each update cycle synchronous? In other words, if I`setTimeout(cb,0)`in a lifecycle method (`componentWillReceiveProps, componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate`, in particular), is it possible that `cb` will be called before the end of the cycle?

Answer (score 0):

Reacts update cycle is guaranteed to be asynchronous.  The update can be started by setProps/React.render or setState.  All of these accept a callback argument for when the update is complete.

If you're worried about this it's either an edge case, or you're doing something strangely.

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't answer my question. I know the update will begin asynchronously with, say, setProps or setState. The question is, does the update cycle ever relinquish control between forceRender, componentWillReceiveProps, componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, and the end the cycle (more precisely, the last component DidMount or componentDidUpdate)? Or, as I said in the OP, can the callback execute before the end of the cycle?

Comment: Yes it relinquishes control.